# SQL difference between different columns from different rows

Tags: oracle

Lets say i have a table as follows:

```
| id | dir | p1  | p2  |
|----------------------|
| a  | x   | 1.2 | 1.3 |
| a  | x   | 1.2 | 1.3 |
| a  | z   | 2.1 | 3   |
| a  | z   | 2.1 | 3   |
| b  | x   | 1   | null|
| b  | z   | 4   | null|
```

I would like to have unique rows of row a and b where dir = x and dir = z. So two rows each.
Then when dir = z. Take the value in p1 - (p2 of the previous row for that id) as newval1 and the value in p2 - (p1 of the previous row for that id) as new val2.
Treating nulls as zeroes.
In steps I suppose it will be:

```
| id | dir | p1  | p2  |
|----------------------|
| a  | x   | 1.2 | 1.3 |
| a  | z   | 2.1 | 3   |
| b  | x   | 1   | null|
| b  | z   | 4   | null|
```

Desired result will be:

```
| id | newval1       | newval2   | 
|--------------------------------|
| a  | 0.8(2.1-1.3)  | 1.8(3-1.2 |
| b  |  4 (4-0)      | -1(0-1)   |
```

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

Comment: mysql or Oracle ?

Comment: If its possible in Oracle that would be ideal.

Comment: In the question, you mention "previous" row several time. That suggests some ordering. Ordering by what? Or are you, instead, using values for row with dir = 'z' minus values from row with dir = 'x'? That does not require any concept of "previous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,
       nvl(max(case when dir = 'z' then p1 end), 0)
         - nvl(max(case when dir = 'x' then p2 end), 0) as newval1,
       nvl(max(case when dir = 'z' then p2 end), 0)
         - nvl(max(case when dir = 'x' then p1 end), 0) as newval2
from   tbl
where  dir in ('x', 'z')
group by id
;

ID    NEWVAL1    NEWVAL2
-- ---------- ----------
a          .8        1.8
b           4         -1
```

Or, if you are on version 11.1 or higher, you can use the `pivot` operator:

```
select id, z_p1 - x_p2 as newval1, z_p2 - x_p1 as newval2
from   tbl
pivot  ( max(nvl(p1, 0)) as p1, max(nvl(p2, 0)) as p2
         for dir in ('x' as x, 'z' as z)
       )
;
```